# Rendering joinTables as a list in Grails

Tags: grails, view, controller, gsp, join

I've got two domain classes: Car and Driver.  I'd like to make a gsp view that displays the Car and Driver info in a list that looks more or less a default scaffolded list.  For example:

```
Make  Model  Driver  Age
------------------------
Chevy Nova   Joe     20
Chevy Nova   Mike    30
Chevy Nova   Sally   40
```

Here's the domain classes:

```
class Car {
  String make
  String model

  static constraints = { }
  static hasMany = [ drivers : Driver ]

  static mapping = {
    drivers joinTable: [name: 'Car_Driver', column: 'DRIVER_ID', key: 'CAR_ID']
  }
}

class Driver {
  String name
  int    age

  static constraints = { }  
}
```

Make a car and give it a few drivers:

```
def car = new Car(make: 'Chevy', model: 'Nova')
def driver1 = new Driver(name: 'Joe', age: 20)
def driver2 = new Driver(name: 'Mike', age: 30)
def driver3 = new Driver(name: 'Sally', age: 40)

car.addToDrivers(driver1)
car.addToDrivers(driver2)
car.addToDrivers(driver3)
car.save()
```

What do I need to do in my CarController and/or gsp view to make a joined list happen (and still work with pagination)?

Comment: Is the relation 1:M or M:M? It's not clear from the example.

Comment: It's a 1:M relationship.  Sorry I didn't make that clear.  Thanks for help!

Comment: You probably meant M:M - looks like a `Car` has many `Driver`s, a `Driver` can drive many `Car`s - that's why join table exists after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Driver` can have only one `Car`, you need a `Driver` to reference `Car` and just to render scaffolding `list` for a `Driver`.

To tweak list columns, you'll have to [`grails generate-views`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html).

If a `Driver` can have many `Cars`, and you don't want to pull `Car_Driver` table into visible domain model (it has no own domain meaning),  make a scaffolding-like `list` action using SQL query result as a `cardriverInstancesList`. Like here: [SQL/Database Views in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425294/sql-database-views-in-grails).

Just check that `result` is a [`PagedResultList`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html). If not, you can create a `PagedResultList` by hand, it is easily constructed from a `List` and `totalCount`, which you can find with SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the [SQL/Database Views in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425294/sql-database-views-in-grails) hint.  That will work nicely. I do have another question though.  In my example, I have multiple cars, each car can have multiple drivers (1:m). How would I pull the Car_Driver jointable into a visible domain model?  That sounds exactly like want I should be doing.

Comment: I meant creating `CarDriver` domain class, mapping it on that table and working with it explicitly. 1. I don't think having this join table in domain model is a good idea, because it violates DDD paradigm - it has no physical sense on its own. Join table is a pure artifact of relational data model limitations. 2. Plus, it will leave you without Grails' methods like `Car.addToDrivers()` - though you can implement those by yourself. 3. Still, it all depends on your requirements and might be not that bad.