# Grails and hsqldb

Tags: grails, groovy, hsqldb

I was wondering how to persist data to a hsqldb. For example I am trying to save a simple name to a database but I cant seem to figure out how to persist it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended approach is to create a domain class with a String name property. Then you can save it, and you're done. First, create the domain class:

```
$ grails create-domain-class com.foo.Person
```

Then edit the grails-app/domain/com/foo/Person.groovy:

```
package com.foo

class Person {
   String name
}
```

In controller actions or service methods you can create, save, and retrieve data:

```
def heMan = new Person(name: 'He Man')
if ( !heMan.save() ) {
   // Handle problems saving (e.g. constraint violations)
}

def h = Person.findByName('He Man')
println h.name
```

An alternative approach is to work with JDBC directly. You can have dataSource bean automatically injected into your controller, then use the groovy.sql.Sql class to query that dataSource. [Check out this stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425294/sql-database-views-in-grails).

Comment: Thanks alot. Also I have another question, Say for instance I wanted to save data from a field in one of my gsp pages into its respective location in a hsql database. Do you have any suggestion on how I should try this?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

- [GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html)
- raw JDBC (via spring's `JdbcTemplate`)

Comment: Not that hard, kind of baked in to the framework--as long as you're working with a Grails model, pretty trivial, no?

Comment: well, it's trivial for me and you, but it might not be that for beginners. Comparatively, I think it's "harder" than the JDBC thing, because it adds the ORM concept, with which you may not be familiar

Comment: But why then bother with grails?

Comment: I think if you're using Grails it's way easier to do it the Grails way since you don't really have to *do* anything, and what you *do* need to do is documented. Stepping outside the framework adds a layer of complexity. OTOH, if something Grails-y *breaks*, then not knowing the underlying frameworks is a serious liability.

Comment: @DaveNewton +1 If you are going to use JDBC, you may as well Groovy by itself

Comment: stepping outside of the framework has given me lots of headaches :) but using a JdbcTemplate isn't such a thing. But I'll reverse the order of the bullets, I agree that gorm is top priority.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with a good Grails [tutorial such as this one at IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/) or [one of these](http://grails.org/Tutorials). Learn to use GORM. It will make your life better.