# Access a SQL Server 2008 View From Grails

Tags: sql-server, grails

We have a Grails project that needs to pull data from a SQL Server 2008 view.  We just need to do a basic select from the view.

Is there a config setting for views such that we can map a domain class to the view?

Or should we use raw SQL like:

```
db.rows("SELECT foo, bar FROM my_view")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL/Database Views in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425294/sql-database-views-in-grails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL, e.g. with `groovy.sql.Sql` as suggested in the other similar question's answer, but it's also possible in a domain class. If you create a domain class (use any sensible name) and specify its table name as the name of the view, you can select from it. You'll have problems creating and updating of course, but if you only want to read then it'll be fine:

```
class SomeDomainClass {
   String foo
   Integer bar
   static mapping = {
      table 'my_view'
   }
}
```

If you name the class MyView then mapping isn't needed since the naming convention applies, but this would be a bad name for the class since using it isn't related to the fact that it's backed by a view.

Note that you'll also have problems when using dbCreate set to "create", "create-drop", or "update" since Hibernate will try to create the table, but it shouldn't cause any real problem and just display an ignorable error like "could not create table 'my_view' since it already exists". And once you move to using database migrations this won't be a problem at all.

Comment: Do you happen to which approach is considered the best practice?

Comment: Using the domain class approach is far more convenient since you have access to all of the query approaches (dynamic finders, criteria queries, etc.) whereas using SQL is more work, and can result in database-specific code that isn't portable.

Comment: Ok because we get errors on startup from hibernate trying to alter the view like it was a table even though the columns already exist.  If they are "ignorable" as Burt stated then we will go ahead and go with the domain class.